# Saving updated UILabel on ViewController until app is closed

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I have a UIView where I can change a status in UILabel with UITextField, but after I shift to another ViewController my UILabel has an old default text.

I'm only a student so I don't need to save info in UserDefaults or something. I just need ViewController to hold update till I close my app.

Do I need to set delegate or I just need to manage something in ViewController?
I don't use storyboards if it matters.

Answer (score 1):

A quick and easy way would be to keep the label string as a static variable.

Here is the sample code for understanding:

```swift
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var label: UILabel = UILabel()

    // Static variable to hold the label text
    static var persistantLabelText: String? = "Default Text"
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        statusLabel.text = ViewController.persistantLabelText
    }
    
    func updateLabel(_ text: String) {
        ViewController.sharedLabelText = text
        statusLabel.text = ViewController.persistantLabelText
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you should consider data storage that is alive for the whole app lifecycle.

Comment: thanks for answer, but I have property changing UILabel in class UIView, how can I transfer my updated UILabel in viewDidLoad of VC?

Comment: This is just a sample code. You can keep your static variable in your UIView as well. The main idea is static variable retain their data throught the app lifecycle.